# AS3 : MovieClip script stop when done playing

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I am a beginner with AS3 and I'm having a problem with MovieClip class. 
I have a character that move through a simple script that handles collision, sound etc. Everything was working seemlessly so far but when I started adding animation, the character would stop at the end of the animation cycle.

Does someone comfortable with AS3 knows what's wrong here ?

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1):

Inside the Flash IDE, try clicking the instance of your character that's not looping the way you want it to (and this should be from outside the animation itself; from the container of your character), then look inside the **Properties** tab/window. Near the bottom, there will be a **LOOPING** header, and inside there you can modify the behaviour.

In case you have any problems with this, or otherwise want to have more control over the animation playhead, you can include script in the form of e.g. `gotoAndPlay(1);` which you might add at the last frame of your animation cycle to tell Flash to play from the start again. The frame number parameter doesn't have to be 1 of course. You could for example set up a series of animation sequences on a single timeline, and use gotoAndPlay() to have them loop internally, until an event occurs and you direct the playhead to another animation loop inside the same MovieClip.

Comment: If your talking about having multiple animations in one movieclip, then I would recommend using framelabels in with gotoandplay, rather than referencing the frame number. this way if your animation lengths change, you can just move the frame labels.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when `play();` is called, an animation is being repeated all the time.

You should seek in your code for `stop();` that essentially makes an animation stop, and remove it.